# Import fails from CSV file into SQL Server 2012 table

Tags: csv, sql-server-2012, delimiter, import-from-csv

I am trying to import a rather large (520k rows) `.CSV` file into a SQL Server 2012 table. The file uses a delimiter of `;`.

Please do not edit my delimiter.  It is ";"  I know that may seem strange, but that is what they used.  It is not just a semicolon.

I don't think the delimiter is the issue because I replaced it with a tab and it seemed to be okay.  When I try importing the file, I get a text truncation error, but I set the column to 255 just to be sure it had plenty of room.

Even when I delete the row, the next row causes the error. I don't see any offending characters in the data, so I am at a loss as to what the issue is.

Comment: try setting the column to 4000. if that doesn't fix it, the row terminator is likely wrong--that is the import is not identifying a new line and thus your entire file is treated as a single row. If a new rows is identified by a new line  (CR/LF) try `\n` or `0x0a`. Ideally, **Post the code** that you are using to import this.

Comment: I am trying to use the import wizard.  Setting the column to 4000 did not fix it.  I still get "The data conversion for column "Loc-Name" returned status 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".  The row delimiter is {LF} and the column delimiter is ";" if that matters.  Usually my row delimiter is {CR}{LF}, but it won't let me use that.  It says it cannot find that in the data.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the EOL Conversion and selected Windows format in Notepad++ and then created a script to import the data.